# How can I translate these sentences expressing probability or uncertainty?

Tags: translation

In Italian I can use the Future Tense not to express something that will surely happen in the future. For example:

- Referring to myself, talking with somebody

  > Andrò a letto. (*I am bored. Maybe it is better I go to sleep.*)
- Referring to somebody else (e.g. because somebody asked me where that person is going)

  > Andrà da suo cugino. (*I am not sure where she is going, but I think probable she is going to her cousin's.*)

Is there a tense or a mood I can use in Esperanto to express probability or uncertainty as in Italian, or is using adverbs the only way to express the same in Esperanto?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, you need an adverb: *eble* (possibly), *probable* (probably), *verŝajne* (it is likely). You can also say *miaopinie* or *laŭ mi* (in my opinion), or *laŭŝajne* or *ŝajnas ke* (it seems that).

> *Verŝajne, ŝi iras al ĉe sia kuzo.* Most likely she's going to her cousin's.

In your first example, you can say "I ought to go to bed" *(Mi devus enlitiĝi)* or "Maybe I had better go to bed" *(Eble pli bonus se mi enlitiĝus)* or you could use the *-u* verb ending, as you are essentially making a recommendation to yourself:

> *Mi enlitiĝu.* [literally] Go to bed, me.

Comment: The last sentence is possible also in Italian, but the Imperative mood is just used for commands. In Italian it would get to mean I am going to bed. (It would not be clear if I use the Present Tense, or the Imperative.) Does Esperanto use the _-u_ verbs for recommendations?

Comment: Yes. The *-u* ending is not just imperative, but technically a "deontic mood", which is much vaguer and covers wishes, aims, recommendations, etc. https://adventuresinesperanto.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/an-interesting-mood/